# ✯ Familiar Faces ✯ \(^ヮ^)/

Tags: language

I invited a bunch of people to a small party:

```
 A. ㇏(う_う)ﾉ

 B. (°ヘ°)

 C. (イ◠‿◠)

 D. ¯\_(シ)_/¯

 E. (メ°皿°)ﾉ
```

Everyone made it and we all had a great time.

---

> I was the second person in the room. She came first, he was last and you came just before me.
>
> In what order did everyone arrive?

Comment: And did any of them flip the table?

Comment: @Randal'Thor ┬─┬ ノ( ゜-゜ノ)

Comment: Maybe my mind is too perverted on a Friday evening, but when I read "_She came first, he was last and you came just before me._" my mind thinks something completely different than what is being implied. ;p Nice challenge btw, especially since I tried to learn Japanese a bit since about two weeks ago with online tutorials. I watch a lot of Japanese anime and sometimes movies lately, and although I suck with languages overall, I'd like to learn reading and speaking Japanese. :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen ,I want to assure you that the wording was entirely innocent! Thank you, I hope you keep trying, I'm still a beginner but it gets less daunting along the way.

Comment: I'm fairly certain native speaker will actually be at a disadvantage with this puzzle.

Comment: @Ambo100 So... no tables were flipped then?

Comment: @SpectralFlame For the purpose of this puzzle, no. But if it was someone, my money would be on E...

Comment: Why didn't you invite Lenny? ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The order is

> D, C, A, E, B

This is because

> I (イ) was the second person in the room. She (シ) came first, he (ヘ) was last and you (う) came just before me (メ).
>
>  In which the characters in the faces are part of the Japanese writing system: イ = I, シ = SHI, ヘ = he, う = u, メ = ME.
>
>  This puzzle works best if you pronounce the character names with an English accent, and not in the way they are actually pronounced in Japanese (for instance, "う = u" sounds different from "you" in Japanese).

Comment: やった! Perfect answer ＼(￣▽￣)／

Comment: What do those words mean which are placed before and after **! Perfect answer** ?

Comment: [‘Yatta’](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%82%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F) means something like ‘hooray!’. The second part is a Kaomoji (face created with characters)

Comment: I believe ‘Yatta’ is closer to “you did it” or “I did it” etc... rather than just a “hooray”. But that’s a literal translation. It is very much used like a “hooray” in this context :-) awesome puzzle and answer. M

Comment: You did it is written 'Yatta ne' which is やったね, 'Yatta' means I did it, instead of you did it.